# Align two icons to the far right of a parent div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add an **svg** and another span element container an **svg** to the far right of an input however, with my current setting they are overlapping:

I have a structure like this:

```css
/* How can I fix this such that the red will be aligned before the arrows? Currently my css is:  */

svg,
#mySvg {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.8;
  right: 0;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -25px;
  z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex align-items-center input-fields">
  <input class="form-control textInput" type="text">
  <svg></svg>
  <span id="mySvg"></span>
</div>
```

currently they look like this: [image]

Comment: text-align:right + float left for input is an old way to do so. , flex, grid can also help efficiently here. With  built-in class from bs4 , it should not be difficult, have you tried any before making custom style ?

Comment: Since you are using Bootstrap, you should not be using position absolute to align your items. You have a very powerful grid system available to you, which is built up by flex-box. You can utilize this to get your desired result. There are multiple ways to achieve this, either by making cols that fill out the exact space available, or having 2 cols, 1 for username, 1 with both icons and use `justify-content: space-between` to align them respectively. You can also make use of the Bootstrap `offset-[n]` class. I highly recommend you read this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: You want to display the icons inside the input field? or outside?

Comment: @AhmadKarimi I want o display the icons inside the fields and not outside them, so I do not know if using bootstrap grid system will be any help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example that I managed to work on for this purpose. You can change your HTML like this:

```
<div class="input-fields">
  <input class="form-control textInput" type="text">
  <div id="icons_container">
    <svg></svg>
    <span id="mySvg">&#9824;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and for the CSS part, you do like this:

```
#icons_container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0px 5px 0 0;
}
```

I have wrapped both the icons with div that is positioned as absolute and it's display property is set to flex.
Here is the example in full in CodePen. https://codepen.io/ahmadkarimi2009/pen/ExgpLbe

**Note: I haven't used Bootstrap for tackling this issue.**

Answer (score -1):

When you using **absolute position** for elements you can not control overlaping them.
The only thing you can do is that add more right offset to one of them to prevent overlaping.
Example:

```css
svg {
    right: 10px;
}

#mySvg {
    right: 40px;
}
```